# Overworking and it usage within sentences?

Tags: phrases

Is it common to say something like:

> If you work in every weekend for 3 months you may get sick because of overwork.

Please correct me if it's clear what I tried to say...

Comment: "If you work every weekend for three months you may get sick from  overwork" is more idiomatic.

Comment: @StoneyB So it's correct to say so, great. Have you personally used such a sentence in your everyday life?

Comment: I don't know if I've ever *said* it, but I've certainly *done* it! In case it's not clear: *overwork* here is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @StoneyB No it's clear. I just made the sentence as transalation from my native lang and was in doubt about its correcness....

Comment: Honestly, I would drop the overwork because it it assumed from context: If you (were to) work every weekend for 3 months, you might get sick."

Comment: I believe the phrase is missing just a word or two to be conversationally idiomatic. _If you **go in to work** every weekend for three months, the overwork may make you sick._

Comment: An aside: when you are forming sentences in English (while speaking or writing) you should **think** in English - translating from your native language is slower, more difficult and wrong (it causes you to make more mistakes and use unidiomatic constructions).

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

I'm feeling sick and overworked because I haven't had a weekend off in three months. (Talking about myself instead of saying to someone else)

Or

You can get sick if you're overworked. (Where you drop the reason for being overworked)

Or

You can feel overworked and get sick if you work three months without taking any weekends off.

Also the first comment:

> "If you work every weekend for three months you may get sick from overwork" is more idiomatic. –  @StoneyB yesterday

However, yours is understandable, I just wouldn't say it that way myself.